# Pasting Excel cells into Inkscape without overlapping?

Tags: inkscape

A strange one, but bear with me... If I copy coloured cells from Excel into a graphics program (in the screenshot I'm using Inkscape), the cells are pasted as individual objects (which is what I want) but they appear to overlap.  I'm trying to make it so that when I paste the cells they do not overlap.

I've tried different settings in Inkscape (snap to grids etc) but am having no luck. I've also tried to see if there's a setting in Excel that would help, but again no luck.

[image]

Comment: I think you'd need to modify the image data in your clipboard to get a different result. As you cannot do that, you probably need to use one of the various alignment and space-setting options in Inkscape.

Answer (score 1):

The overlapping may be due to your Excel version. I am using Excel 2007, but I don't get overlapping cells. Please look the below images.
[image]
[image]